# Poisson Point Process for Conditional Probability

Tags: probability

[image]

I am confused as to what questions A and B are asking and therefore have issue setting up these problems.  I know that T has the Poisson distribution parameter lambda and the wait time between arrivals are independent exponentials with parameter lambda.  But I don't know how to link them together for conditional density.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

For part (a), it might be a little strange to think about the conditional distribution of $T_2$ given $T_3,$ but it isn't too bad to think about the conditional distribution of $T_3$ given $T_2.$ After all, we know that $T_3-T_2$ is an exponential, so $T_3$ given $T_2=t_2$ is just an exponential shifted to the right by $t_2.$ Then we can appeal to Bayes to get $T_2$ conditional on $T_3$. We also need the densities of $T_2$ and $T_3,$ but these are sums of independent exponentials, and thus Gamma distributed.

There is another way to look at it as well: the arrivals have constant intensity and all we know is the third one happens at time $1.$ The first two arrivals should be pretty much uniform in the interval before that. So it is reasonable to expect (and can be shown) that the earlier arrivals are conditionally jointly distributed as order statistics of independent uniforms. So your conditional distribution for $T_2$ should have the same distribution as the maximum of two independent $U(0,1)$'s.

For part (b) the event $\{N_1=2\}=\{T_2<1\}$ so once you convince yourself of this, you just need to compute the distribution of $T_2$ given that $T_2<1.$